# Meaning of 声をそろえる

Tags: translation, nuances, set-phrases

What is the meaning of 声をそろえる in this conversation:

> 「だからってドロボーの手伝いまですることないじゃない」
>   お姉ちゃんがあきれたように言うと、ヒロシも**声をそろえた**。
>   「そうだぞ。そんなバカなことしない人間に育てるために、厳しくする方がまる子のためだ。...」

Literally I think it means 'to gather/collect/prepare ones voice'.

In English we have the phrase 'collect one's thoughts' e.g. "He collected his thoughts and then answered the question". So I can think of three possibilities:

1) It's a combination of collecting your thoughts and then speaking

2) You've become temporarily speechless, because someone said something stupid for example, and you are getting the ability to speak again.

3) If そろえる means 'prepare' then maybe it means something like clearing your throat

Are any of these correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「[声]{こえ}をそろえる」

in this context, means:

> "to say (basically) the same thing about something as others have previously said about it"

or in short,

> "to express a similar opinion"

In other situations such as multiple people singing or saying the same thing together ,　「声をそろえる」 means:

> "to sing in unison" or "to speak in one voice" respectively.

Comment: +1. Thank you, your answer cleared up what I said.

Answer (score 1):

It means: to speak in unison (with one voice). A synonym is 声を合わせる.

EDIT: I think that what you said in your first comment seems to apply here. Hiroshi agrees with oneechan. Hiroshi made his opinion merge with oneechan's opinion when he says 「そうだぞ。。...」.

Comment: There's only one person speaking though. Do you mean unison in the sense that the person speaking is agreeing with and affirming what the previous person said? That would make a lot of sense.

Comment: That is strange, I have only seen this expression when there are multiple voices that say/sing something all at the same time. Could you give a bit more context?

Comment: I added some context.